# How to filter out the effect of fire flames from an image

Tags: image-processing, aforge

What is the most effective way to reduce the effect of fire flames from an image. I am trying to remove light from welding using aforge library

http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/cdf93487-0659-e371-fed9-3b216efb6954.htm

[image]

[image]

Comment: what have you tried? where are the sample images? Any DIP/CV question without sample input image is unanswerable.

Comment: I have tried BrightnessCorrection, ColorFiltering, ChannelFiltering adn few others

Comment: If you do not add some sample image(s) you are dealing with no one can help you ...

Comment: Picture added, looking for option to remove the flames and to get closer look at the objects

Comment: there is not much you can do as the flame is yellow (red,green saturated) and the whole image contains almost no information in blue band. That means you can not distinguish between flame and information. No matter what you do with naive filtering you will not gain anything useful. There are options however. 1. Add a blue light to illuminate the scene while taking the shot. or 2. do a physical simulation of light propagation and remove computed halos from image but this is hardcore you need scene mesh approximation, and simulate light scattering in volume (not easy)

Comment: Thank you  Spektre. We were thinking about illuminating the scene with light. Could you explain remove halos and mesh.

Comment: The #1 is easy just place blue lamp ... and take only Blue band from the image. The #2  approach is too broad subject. In an nutshell you create Voxel map of your workspace (raw approximate of it suffice) and make a physical simulation of the light source light propagation. Then project that onto camera to obtain ilumination image which you have to scale and substract from the real camera image. This way you should remove most of the unwanted lighting. But it is hard to say if any useful information will be left this way if camera image does not contain information you can not get it from it.

Comment: The simulation is really hard in this case as you need to include Light scattering both MIE and Rayleight, thermodynamics of fluids, aerodynamic temperature effects, and much more .... as I am no expert in most of the fields I am not confident to advice more ...

Comment: @Spektre - illuminated the scene with blue. Tried different filters but no result. Any help or suggestions possible

Comment: wow that is actually worse then the first try most likely your camera can not handle the HDR class distribution of light and most of the halos are not real but an effect caused by the camera itself (in CCD case the charge can jump to neighboring cells if too big, for CMOS I do not know but likely similar effect can be present). To improve quality try manual exposition setting and you can use something like [Coronagraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronagraph) to significantly limit the problems (if your camera is fixed) you can use sticker on glass or something...

Comment: I captured this from my iphone. any suggestion on camera could be of help!

Comment: I make some hints and suggestions and explanations as an answer read it and comment me if you need further info

Answer (score 0):

1. **camera**

   You need a proper camera  with normal objective. Phones have too small diameter of the input lenses which cause lower light sensitivity, lower detail, and the chips are usually designed for outdoor/indoor almost uniform lighting conditions. Also phones have usually chips with lower quality.

   If you use any camera hand held camera (does not matter which brand) even a compact would do the image should be much better. I would most definatelly use **CCD** chip instead of **CMOS** (even if the manufactors claims the **CMOS** sensitivity is now in range of the **CCD** which was far from truth in the past then **CCD** is a quarantee that it will work)
2. **Coronagraph**

   To improve image quality the best you can do is physicaly remove the problem before image acquisition. Coronagraph is the way. You just place some non transparent obstacle before camera that will hide the main source of light (arc,flame or whatever causing optical and electrical problems inside camera). This will allow to use higher exposition times to reveal the darker parts of the scene.

   [image: coronagraph]

   The real halos due to light scattering will persist of coarse. This will reduce/remove the over-saturated part of image that can jump/corrupt also neighboring image areas in both optics and the sensor chip itself. There are some special cameras out there that have feature that limits light spikes (used in better surveillance cameras) which are doing almost the same thing as coronagraph but only inside chip area (electrically blocks higher charges) so optics problems are persistent.
3. **Light**

   You should have strong enough light with wavelength safely different to the flame/arc so you can distinguish what is unwanted halo and what is wanted detail. There is a problem that cameras are tri-chromat  with use of [Bayer filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_filter) which makes them sensitive only to R,G,B. The problem is that you do not know how narrow/wide are the band pass filters and if you choose the light wavelengt in wrong part of the band pass filters you can have part of the blue light also registered inside R or G bands or not registered at all (the bands can be overlapped or have gaps between themselves).

   To improve quality you can play with different light sources. If you got the flame/arc light with a specific wavelength you can place an optical filter before the camera that will remove it completely (instead or with the Coronagraph) but for that you would need a spectroscope to see what spectra the flame/arc have (narrow band or fully distributed spectra along visible range). The same can be done for the illumination light source but use a bandpass filter this time so it will block anything else).

   If you do not have spectroscope (or you are not able to do one yourself it is not that hard to do in home conditions) then you need to know more about the physical process creating the light. For some the spectra and or wavelength can be computed/estimated but that is way outside my expertise.
4. **DIP**

   You can extract useful data from the image only if the image contains them. That is why you should implement the bullets **#1,#2,#3**. As you first image has most of the halos in green/yellow I expected by illuminating your scene with strong blue light that the details in the scene should be much more visible.

   Your try was a failure most likely due to 2 reasons:

   - The over-saturation is corrupting neighboring pixels due to scattering inside camera optics (Heavy Pb glass is much better then plastic but you can forget about glass in phones).
   - Too big charge can jump (non destructively) between sensor pixels. This usually cause the very bright horizontal or vertical lines going through the light source in the image on **CCD** chips. Have no experience with **CMOS** (I avoid them if I can)

   My bet is the first cause is the worst for you right now but as I have no experience with **CMOS** in this area it may be as well the second (doubt you got **CCD** in phone). The strange gap between the corrupted areas can be cause by charge jump between reading buses instead of pixels itself but also by reflection in between the lenses. Here is how I see it:

   [image: over-saturation]

   If I am right most of the bluish selected areas are not really visible if you look with your eyes and are created inside camera.

   There is no visible details apart of the flame/arc so my bet is that you used wavelength that is fully blocked by the bayer filter (**if there is no flame/arc can you see anything on image?**) or you just have very short exposition time (flame/arc is too much strong in comparison to the blue light). In the first case you need to change light and in the second coronagraph will make your life easier.

   Anyway from resulting image (actually containing some useful data) use only band (r,g,b) that has no or least amount of light from the flame/arc. You can also try to remove the flame/arc from the other two bands with something like:

   ```
   R'=R-min(R,G);
   G'=G-min(R,G);
   ```

   or play with scales etc. But as I mention before first you need to have proper input image containing useful/selectable data.